# how to switch between front and back camera when click a button with surfaceview in android

Tags: android, camera

I am developing one application.In that i want to display front and back cameras. when am opening app it will display back camera it is working fine. But when click a button for opening front camera it does not display. Individually front and back cameras work perfectly. default camera is back camera when click button it will change to front camera again click that button it will change to back camera.how can i do this. can any body tell me please. i am sending my source code please see once and tell me what mistake is there in code. Please tell me am new to android development..

```
CamTestActivity.java


*public class CamTestActivity extends Activity {
 private static final String TAG = "CamTestActivity";
 Preview preview;
 Button buttonClick,savee,front,zoomin,zoomout;
 Camera camera;
 Activity act;
 Context ctx;
 ImageView imm,aboveimg;
 LayoutInflater controlInflater ;
 Camera.Parameters params;
 public RelativeLayout layout,rlayout;
 Bitmap bitmap=null;
 SurfaceHolder surfaceholder;
 int myScreenHeight = 0;
 int myScreenWidth = 0;
 Bitmap bmapoverlay;
 public static ZoomControls zoom;
 byte[] dataaa;
 Bitmap bitmapPicture;
 int  maxZoomLevel=0;
 int currentZoomLevel = 0;
 private int cameraId= Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
 boolean inPreview;
 int currentCameraId;
 int which=0;
 private int cameraType;
 int camIdx = 0;
 boolean previewing = false;
 @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
 int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
 int numberOfCamera;
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ctx = this;
    act = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
    rlayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rrlayout);
    preview = new Preview(this, (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
    preview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    imm=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    aboveimg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    rlayout.addView(preview);
    aboveimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.design);
    //layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    buttonClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    // camera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
    zoomin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    zoomout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    front=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //setCameraDisplayOrientation(CamTestActivity.this, currentCameraId, camera);
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    });
    zoomin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            preview.zoom();
        }
    });
    zoomout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            preview.unzoom();
        }
    });
    /*// do we have a camera?
    if (!getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
    } else {
        cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
        if (cameraId < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
        }
    }*/
    front.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            openFrontFacingCamera();
        }
    });
    }
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   public void openFrontFacingCamera() {
    numberOfCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
        camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BACK TO FRONT" ,
                1000).show();
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = Camera.open(camId);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceholder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {}
     }else if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
        camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FRONT TO BACK" , 1000).show();
        try {
            camera.release();
            camera = Camera.open(camId);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceholder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {}
      }
    }
     /*@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            // Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
            cameraId = i;
            break;
        }
       }
      return cameraId;
   }*/
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //      preview.camera = Camera.open();
    camera = Camera.open();
    camera.startPreview();
    preview.setCamera(camera);
    //camera.stopPreview();
   }
   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
    if(camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        preview.setCamera(null);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
    }
    private void resetCam() {
    camera.startPreview();
    preview.setCamera(camera);
    }
    private void refreshGallery(File file) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
    }
    };
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //           Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
    };
   PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //dataaa=data;
        //new SaveImageTask().execute(data);        
        bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        imm.setImageBitmap(bitmapPicture);
        resetCam();
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        layout.getRootView();
        layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        layout.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap m=layout.getDrawingCache();
        // Write to SD Card
        try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
            dir.mkdirs();           
            String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            m.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream);
            outStream.write(data[0]);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());
            refreshGallery(outFile);
            imm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        //buttonClick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //savee.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "display", 1000).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
         };



  Preview.java

   class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
   protected static final String camera = null;
   Camera.Parameters params;
  private final String TAG = "Preview";
  protected Camera.Size mPictureSize;
  protected Activity mActivity;
  SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
  SurfaceHolder mHolder;
   Size mPreviewSize;
  List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
  Camera mCamera;
  Context context;
  int currentZoomLevel ;
  int maxZoomLevel ;
  boolean previewing = false;
  int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;



   //private TutorialThread _thread;
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   Preview(Context context, SurfaceView sv) {
    super(context);
    mSurfaceView = sv;
    //        addView(mSurfaceView);
    mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    //params = mCamera.getParameters();
    }
    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
     mCamera = camera;
     if (mCamera != null) {
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        requestLayout();
        // get Camera parameters
        params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            // set the focus mode
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            // set Camera parameters
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
       }
     }
     @Override
       protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
      // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
       // of stretching it.
       final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
       final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
       setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
       if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
        }
        @Override
       protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
         if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
        final View child = getChildAt(0);
        final int width = r - l;
        final int height = b - t;
        int previewWidth = width;
        int previewHeight = height;
        if (mPreviewSize != null) {
            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
        }
        // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
        if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
            final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
            child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                    (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
        } else {
            final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
            child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                    width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
        }
        }
        }
      @SuppressLint({ "WrongCall", "NewApi" })
       public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder) {
     // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
     // to draw.
     /* params.setRotation(90);
      mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);*/
      try {
        if (mCamera != null) {
           // mCamera=Camera.open(camId);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            params = mCamera.getParameters();
            params.set("orientation", "portrait");
            params.setRotation(90);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);

            //////////


        }
       } catch (IOException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
         }
        }

      public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
          if (mCamera != null) {
           mCamera.stopPreview();
           mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            previewing = false;
         }
         }
         private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
       final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
         double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;
          Size optimalSize = null;
         double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            int targetHeight = h;
           // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
               for (Size size : sizes) {
         double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
         if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
         if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
           }
           }
           // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
             if (optimalSize == null) {
              minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
           for (Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
            }
              }
           return optimalSize;
            }
         public void zoom()
          {

        params=mCamera.getParameters();
        maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
        if (currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel) {
            currentZoomLevel++;
            params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
        /*if(currentZoomLevel < 50){
        params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel= currentZoomLevel + 10);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);   
        }else{

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no zoom here..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/

          }
    public void unzoom()
    {
        params=mCamera.getParameters();
        maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
        if (currentZoomLevel > 0) {
            currentZoomLevel--;
            params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
        /*if(currentZoomLevel >0){
        params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel= currentZoomLevel - 10);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }else{
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
       */
      }
       public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
       if(previewing){
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        previewing = false;
     }
      // params=mCamera.getParameters();
     if(mCamera != null) {
        params=mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        //mCamera.setParameters(cameraParams);
        //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        previewing=true;


        }

        }
        }*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for front camera :

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
int cameraCount = 0;
Camera cam = null;
Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx<cameraCount; camIdx++) {
    Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        try {
            cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Your_TAG", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    } 
    return cam;
}
```

Refer [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html)

Comment: Individually front and back camera is working.but when i click button for back to front it does not working.how can i do this.

Comment: above code is working for displaying back and front cameras but in this default camera is back. when am click a switch button back camera is stopped and nothing will be displayed.when am close and open app in that time it will display front face camera. I want to show when i click switch button it will display front face camera. how can i refresh and display cameras. please help me.